# How to specify rust Box type in Box::<_>::new()

Tags: rust

It is strange that in the code snippet below, the second function compiles, but not the third.

```rust
pub fn foo1(iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> ) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> {
      Box::new(iter.map(|n| n + 1)) 
} // This compiles

pub fn foo2(iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> ) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> {
    let a: Box::<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::<_>::new(iter.map(|n| n + 1));
    a
} // This also compiles

pub fn foo3(iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> ) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> {
    let a: Box::<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>::new(iter.map(|n| n + 1));
    a   
} // This does not compile
```

How should we specify `Box::<_>::new` in the third funciton to make it compiles, and why?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e114a0b9151370359c6703be21bfdd3f)

Comment: Rust will automatically cast into a `dyn Trait`. But, `Box::new` requires `Sized`. In foo2, the type of the right hand side is something like `Box<Map<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>, {{closure}}>>`, which is cast to `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>` when assigned to `a`.

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ. I think I forgot `Sized` was default constrait when I looked at `Box::new()` declaration!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first and second version, the function you call is *not* `<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>>::new()`.  This function [requires `T: Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new), but `dyn Iterator: !Sized`. Rather, you call `<Box<SomeConcreteType>>::new()`, and coerce the result to `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>`.

The fully type-ascribed version is:

```rust
pub fn foo3(iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> {
    let a: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::<
        std::iter::Map<
            Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>, // The original iterator type
            _,                            // The callback type (cannot be named using stable Rust)
        >,
    >::new(iter.map(|n| n + 1))
        as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;
    a
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there any other way to specify a `Box<dyn trait>` than type ascripition or `as`?

Comment: And it totally makes sense that `Box::new` needs `T: Sized`. It has to allocate memory, after all. And for the, it needs to know the exact size. And re @WiSaGaN: you can also write `<Box<T>>::new()`.

Comment: @WiSaGaN You can let the compiler coerce it in any way, for example by specifying the type in a `let` declaration. Do you have a concrete example where you need that?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I was just trying to return the `Box` directly, so I want to avoid introduce another binding. Guess I can just use `as`.

Comment: @WiSaGaN Return type position can also cause coercion. Basically, in every place when we have one type, but another type is expected, a coercion takes place if possible.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I guess it works less reliably when it is a `Result<Box<_>, _>` and the `Box` is wrapped inside a `Result::map`? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0286fc05e0a8ad78a15190f3e204ca2

Comment: @WiSaGaN Oh yeah, coercion places are surprising sometimes. Though adding a just `as _` [is enough to hint the compiler to perform the coercion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a190a980d29454082f676c1071862ee) (this boils down to complicated rules where the compiler is allowed to perform coercions and where not).

Comment: @WiSaGaN [Coercion sites - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites).